Checking why an NFS mount gives an error
I'm asking on behalf of a friend's son who is at college in India, so apologies if what I ask doesn't have enough information. He is using WSL2 on Windows 11 and has Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS installed.
His prof has given these instructions for mounting an NFS share needed for the course:
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
cd /
sudo mkdir tools
sudo mount -t nfs 10.0.17.82:/tools /tools

The first three commands work fine but the mount fails. I got him to add a -v flag and the output is:
minor@Tejas:~$ sudo mkdir /tools
[sudo] password for minor:
minor@Tejas:~$ ls /tools
minor@Tejas:~$ sudo mount -v -t nfs 10.0.17.82:/tools /tools
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sun Sep  8 15:10:40 2024
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=10.0.17.82,clientaddr=172.29.144.144'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,minorversion=1,addr=10.0.17.82,clientaddr=172.29.144.144'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Operation not permitted
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=10.0.17.82'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 10.0.17.82 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 10.0.17.82 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 20048
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: Operation not permitted
minor@Tejas:~$

I asked him to use showmount and the result was:
minor@Tejas:~$ showmount -e 10.0.17.82
Export list for 10.0.17.82:
/ *

I can't see a /tools export in the list, but then I don't know if I should be able to see it. It's entirely possible his prof has not configured the server properly.
Anyhow can anyone suggest what is wrong, or further steps to check what the problem is?

the OP addressed in this recent answer was also using NFS. There may be something there to go on. BTW you have tagged 12.04 - did you really mean 22.04? Please [edit] accordingly to avoid confusion. 12.04 is now EOL and off-topic

Oops, yes, it should have been 22.04. Thanks :-)

add more v's (up to 5) and you get more details but to me it looks like the issue is on whatever 10.0.17.82  is.  If you want to skip some of the errors add the version to the command (4.2 and 4 are not supported on your version from the looks of it) "I can't see a /tools export in the list" it is probably the root of the mount. Add a dir or file to /tools and you probably get it listed. Can you check  /etc/exports on the server?

@Rinzwind Thanks :-) We have no access to the server so I guess we can only email the prof and hope he sorts it out.

Your details (if accurate) do highlight security fixes have not been applied in a rather long time (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 22.04.4 but installed systems upgraded before that date, your details show you're still on 22.04.3).  I'll suggest applying security fixes & other updates asap as your details show you're 6+ months behind (if using a Ubuntu system)

@guiverc we have done a sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade on the WSL installation. Is that what you meant? The MS store lists 22.04.3 as the latest version for v22, though I've just looked and it does have 24.04.

You are correct (and I'm aware that this file ( https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts ) also only mentions 22.04.3 but don't know why) so I maybe missing something sorry... I know what I said applies to standard amd64, armhf, arm64, ppc64el, s390x, riscv64, etc architectures, but maybe doesn't apply to WSL you're using..  Maybe my comment does not apply.

The issue may be that the prof's server uses the NFS secure export option - at least, I get the same behavior from a WSL2 Ubuntu instance to an Ubuntu 24.04 nfs server and it starts working if I change the server's /etc/exports to use insecure. AFAIK the Ubuntu nfs client uses a privileged port by default - but that likely gets "translated" to a non-privileged port on the Windows host because WSL runs behind a NAT interface - the secure export mounts fine from another Ubuntu system on a bridged VirtualBox VM.

... another piece of evidence for the unprivileged port # hypothesis: after enabling server-side logging as described here Where are NFS v4 logs under systemd? I can see mounting from WSL fails with refused mount request from 192.168.1.9 for /home/steeldriver (/home): illegal port 63936 (note 192.168.1.9 is the IP address of the WSL instance's Windows host)

@steeldriver My friend's son is going to dual boot Ubuntu rather than using WSL, then see if that works. This will be a few days but if you want to post an answer now I'm sufficiently convinced this is the reason to accept your answer.

@JohnRennie thanks, I have added an answer - please let us know if they are able to resolve the issue one way or another

It's hard to make a definitive diagnosis without seeing the server-side NFS logs1, however the behavior might be explained by the fact that the WSL network interface uses Network Address Translation (NAT) which causes the client-side source port to appear to be non-privileged, while the server exports the remote filesystem using the secure option - which only permits connections from privileged ports.
To demonstrate, I configured nfs-kernel-server on a Kubuntu 24.04 box with the following /etc/exports file:
/               192.168.1.0/24(rw,nohide,secure,no_subtree_check,sync)

and created a /tools directory with a dummy /tools/sometool file, then tried to mount it from a VirtualBox VM running Ubuntu 22.04 with a NAT interface:

Host (Windows) IP: 192.168.1.9

Guest (Ubuntu 22.04) IP: 10.0.2.15 (NAT)
  $ sudo mount -t nfs -vvv 192.168.1.26:/tools /tools
  mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon Sep  9 17:33:09 2024
  mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.168.1.26,clientaddr=10.0.2.15'
  mount.nfs: mount(2): Operation not permitted
  mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.26'
  mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
  mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.26 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
  mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
  mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.26 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 43961
  mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
  mount.nfs: Operation not permitted


Server-side log:
 Sep 09 13:31:09 htpc rpc.mountd[457645]: refused mount request from 192.168.1.9 for /tools (/): illegal port 58242



Note the high-numbered (>1024) source port in the error message illegal port 58242.
Re-configuring the VM interface in bridged mode:

Host (Windows) IP: 192.168.1.9

Guest (Ubuntu 22.04) IP: 192.168.1.22 (BRIDGED)
  $ sudo mount -t nfs -vvv 192.168.1.26:/tools /tools
  mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon Sep  9 17:38:28 2024
  mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.168.1.26,clientaddr=192.168.1.22'
  $ 
  $ ls /tools
  sometool



Server-side log:
    Sep 09 13:36:28 htpc rpc.mountd[457645]: auth_unix_ip: inbuf 'nfsd 192.168.1.22'
    Sep 09 13:36:28 htpc rpc.mountd[457645]: successful authentication for IP 192.168.1.22 as 192.168.1.0/24
    Sep 09 13:36:28 htpc rpc.mountd[457645]: auth_unix_ip: client 0x5d0dce71bef0 '192.168.1.0/24'

For further evidence that it's the non-privileged port that's the problem, I then tried adding the noresvport option to the mount command on the bridged VM:
    sudo mount -t nfs -onoresvport -vvv 192.168.1.26:/tools /tools

and got the same behaviour as for the NAT configuration.
Some possible workarounds are:

It may be possible to configure WSL to use a bridged interface, as described in this blog for example How to brigde [sic] Windows Subsystem for Linux
However that's outside the scope of this site.

You could switch to a "bare metal" Ubuntu installation, or a virtualization solution that permits bridged interfacing out of the box like Oracle Virtualbox or VMware.

You could ask your prof to modify the export to permit non-privileged port numbers - if it's a modern Linux based server, that would mean adding the insecure option (or changing secure to insecure):



   secure This option requires that requests not using gss originate on an
          Internet  port  less than IPPORT_RESERVED (1024). This option is
          on by default.  To turn it off, specify insecure.


For further information see

man exports in Section 5 of the Ubuntu manpages

the SECURITY CONSIDERATIONS section of man nfs



If the prof's server is running a systemd-based Linux then logging isn't enabled by default, but may be enabled by following the instructions here Where are NFS v4 logs under systemd?

Thanks. WSL supports bridging but it requires adding HyperV so we're going to let this one go and use Ubuntu Live instead. WSL has NIC mirroring built in but MS warn it is flaky and when I tried it the mount command timed out.
